# Can "texting" include emails?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Texting is a word for sending a text message via the Short Message Service (SMS) and available in cell phone services now, distinguished from email.

But I would like to know how strictly you use those words. When you are asked to text a message, should it mean strictly texting via SMS? When you say to someone "text a message", do you expect only texting via SMS or either way--texting or emailing?

Comment: Why would you think it means emails, as well?

Comment: @ Tristan r I am not an English native speaker. I was wondering the usage.

Comment: Here in England and the rest of the UK, people just use the word *texting* to mean text messages on mobile phones. The terms SMS and *cell phone* are not normally, used here. I have not heard them in use, at all.

Answer (score 1):

I've only heard the verb "to text" used to refer to SMS.

The closet computer-network equivalent is known by several terms. The most common of those may be "IM", derived from "Instant Message", which was the name of one particular tool.

Note that this is *not* e-mail, which is an entirely different set of protocols and applications and behaviors. Nor is it a chat session, which is yet another set of protocols and applications and behaviors.

Until it's possible to send messages from one of these to another without being aware of the difference, we will continue to need separate terms for them.

Answer (score 1):

No, it cannot. Email and SMS are completely different entities, use different protocols on the technical side, and use different conventions and language on the content side. It confuses people if you use one to mean the other.

Comment: And then something like iMessage comes along to muddy everything up—where you _text_ (?) your friends from your email address to their phone numbers (or any other combination thereof), using the built-in SMS app on the phone, or an IM-like app on a computer. Terminology mayhem ensues.